# I can't send emails with python

Tags: python, gmail

```
from mailer import Mailer
mail = Mailer(email='my email', password='my password')

mail.send(receiver='random email', subject="test", message="Cool reset")
```

When I run this I get an error, it says

Error: Email And Password Not Accepted.

Note:
Make sure you Allowed less secure apps,
if you didn't, visit this link:
==> https://myaccount.google.com/lesssecureapps

```
For More information visit this link:
==> https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials
```

I've already set the "Allow less secure apps" to on.

Btw the email credentials aren't the actual ones I use in my code

Comment: Check https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials.

Answer (score -1):

The following works for me with my own credentials, you will just want to replace the curly braces with your data (EX: mail = Mailer("email", "password")):

```
from mailer import Mailer

mail = Mailer("{sender_email}", "{sender_password}")
mail.send(receiver="{receiver_email}", subject="{subject}", message={"message"})
```

I found this [documentation for quick-mailer](https://www.codegrepper.com/code-examples/python/python+mailer). Perhaps the issue is the use of single quotes, maybe try using only double quotes?

Take another stab at it with that info, good luck.